# Adding gestures to a draggable view? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, touches

I've got `buttons` on my `view` that are `draggable` using `touches` **began/moved/ended**.
I want to add a `tapped` and `doubletapped` actions for my `buttons`. Once I switch my button's class to `UIButton` the action I've created works, but once I change it back to `DraggableView` the actions stop being called because I guess touchesBegan overrides any other touches on the view.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: You should change from `touches began` to the tap+drag gesture on that view, then you can track everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to implement `UITapGestureRecogizer` delegate in your class and add following line of code.

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
tap.delegate = self
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
yourButton.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you